# Align text on the left, image floating on the right and vertically centered inside a <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

As the title says, I have an HTML table with some columns. In one of these columns, which has `width: auto` I would like to display the text left aligned and and an **image/icon right aligned** and floating, because the image is **optional** (i.e. some rows may not have it and I want the text to use all the available space in the `<td>` in that case).

Here's the JSFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4d8foL32/2/

Basically the code is this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>4000.4</td>
  <td>Lemon soda<img src=""></td><!-- This is the line -->
  <td>10/10/2021</td>
  <td>London, United Kingdom</td>
  <td>Waiting</td>
</tr>
```

```css
img {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

There are 2 issues I would like to solve:

1. I would like the image always to be vertically centered on the row

   [image: Problem 1]
2. When reducing the browser window width (and hence the table width), the text doesn't split on a new line keeping the image on the right.

   [image: Problem 2]

The image should keep a small padding on the left to not go over the text. Which is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class to respective td (let assume xyz). And add some flex properties to the class.

```
<td class="xyz">Lemon soda<img src=""></td>

.xyz { 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: space-between // or space-around (if you need some space);
}
```

Note: Remove img style from css or else it will affect the solution.

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a solution, you can use `position: absolute` and align by vertically with `transform: translateY()`. And in `table tbody td:nth-child(2)` add  `padding-right` to create extra space for the icon.

```css
table tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 2em; /* new line */
  position: relative; /* new line */
}

img {
  position: absolute; /* new line */
  right: 0; /* new line */
  top: 50%; /* new line */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* new line */
  /* float: right; */
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 98%;
}

table th,
table td {
  /* Default text alignment */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  /* Separate border */
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

/* Header */
table th {
  background: #0093dd;
  color: white;
}

/* Footer */
table tfoot::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
}

table tfoot td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

table tfoot td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

/* Alternate line colors */
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #efefef;
}

/* Description column left aligned */
table tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 2em; /* new line */
  position: relative; /* new line */
}

/* Columns width */
table tbody td:nth-child(1),
table tbody td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 90px;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  width: auto;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 90px;
}

table tbody td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 160px;
}

/* I would like the image to be right aligned inside the <td> and vertically centered */
img {
  position: absolute; /* new line */
  right: 0; /* new line */
  top: 50%; /* new line */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* new line */
  /* float: right; */
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SKU</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Availability</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>4000.4</td>
          <td>
            Lemon soda<img
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQANUAAA5TiDmd6nmDihZ2v057nStqmZSntR1djhyP52Sy7lRod9TX2RZzuhIoOYKftiiHz1es7WB+loqZpjGBvj1znDKZ6TBqlpCqvyxmkpqsulKCpkKi6yiV6GGCm5apt0Gh605/pGaEm4Wit5+wvY6cpz2f6y1plzWb6YOhtz5zmzNrlVis7UWj6zCBv////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEHAC4ALAAAAAAQABAAAAZoQJdwSCwKisIRQcMEWRRIl+GRqJ5YAAxyWk1MSA1OocjtphYSxHhY7pYok83alaF27wm5sI2vfkwuHnZ9VSsMFy4qhF0QDA5CIQGLjY9DERV9EAOVRJd3mpxFngmgUZYVpaZDHQcipkEAOw=="
            />
          </td>
          <td>10/10/2021</td>
          <td>London, United Kingdom</td>
          <td>Waiting</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3000.3</td>
          <td>
            Orange juice<img
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQANUAAA5TiDmd6nmDihZ2v057nStqmZSntR1djhyP52Sy7lRod9TX2RZzuhIoOYKftiiHz1es7WB+loqZpjGBvj1znDKZ6TBqlpCqvyxmkpqsulKCpkKi6yiV6GGCm5apt0Gh605/pGaEm4Wit5+wvY6cpz2f6y1plzWb6YOhtz5zmzNrlVis7UWj6zCBv////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEHAC4ALAAAAAAQABAAAAZoQJdwSCwKisIRQcMEWRRIl+GRqJ5YAAxyWk1MSA1OocjtphYSxHhY7pYok83alaF27wm5sI2vfkwuHnZ9VSsMFy4qhF0QDA5CIQGLjY9DERV9EAOVRJd3mpxFngmgUZYVpaZDHQcipkEAOw=="
            />
          </td>
          <td>12/11/2021</td>
          <td>Paris, France</td>
          <td>Shipped</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2000.2</td>
          <td>
            An unknown long product to drink when you would like<img
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQANUAAA5TiDmd6nmDihZ2v057nStqmZSntR1djhyP52Sy7lRod9TX2RZzuhIoOYKftiiHz1es7WB+loqZpjGBvj1znDKZ6TBqlpCqvyxmkpqsulKCpkKi6yiV6GGCm5apt0Gh605/pGaEm4Wit5+wvY6cpz2f6y1plzWb6YOhtz5zmzNrlVis7UWj6zCBv////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEHAC4ALAAAAAAQABAAAAZoQJdwSCwKisIRQcMEWRRIl+GRqJ5YAAxyWk1MSA1OocjtphYSxHhY7pYok83alaF27wm5sI2vfkwuHnZ9VSsMFy4qhF0QDA5CIQGLjY9DERV9EAOVRJd3mpxFngmgUZYVpaZDHQcipkEAOw=="
            />
          </td>
          <td>09/11/2021</td>
          <td>Berlin, Germany</td>
          <td>Waiting</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1000.1</td>
          <td>
            Pineapple juice 500 ml<img
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQANUAAA5TiDmd6nmDihZ2v057nStqmZSntR1djhyP52Sy7lRod9TX2RZzuhIoOYKftiiHz1es7WB+loqZpjGBvj1znDKZ6TBqlpCqvyxmkpqsulKCpkKi6yiV6GGCm5apt0Gh605/pGaEm4Wit5+wvY6cpz2f6y1plzWb6YOhtz5zmzNrlVis7UWj6zCBv////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEHAC4ALAAAAAAQABAAAAZoQJdwSCwKisIRQcMEWRRIl+GRqJ5YAAxyWk1MSA1OocjtphYSxHhY7pYok83alaF27wm5sI2vfkwuHnZ9VSsMFy4qhF0QDA5CIQGLjY9DERV9EAOVRJd3mpxFngmgUZYVpaZDHQcipkEAOw=="
            />
          </td>
          <td>24/12/2021</td>
          <td>&mdash;</td>
          <td>&mdash;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1001.5</td>
          <td>
            This product doesn't have any icon and should use all the space
          </td>
          <td>03/12/2021</td>
          <td>&mdash;</td>
          <td>Waiting</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="">&lt; Prev</a></td>
          <td colspan="3">Products 1-5 of 2124</td>
          <td><a href="">Next &gt;</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Although this works on aligning the image, `padding-right: 2em;` on the `<td>` element causes rows without the `<img>` to not consume all the space for the text.